# Add jQuery dropdown effect

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I want to add jQuery dropdown effect to the menu shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5KRjN/

Any Slide or Toggle effect !!

Please help

Comment: http://jquery.com, happy learning

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/outlinemenu.shtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this just by adding a style properties for inner `li` tags.

Html code should be like,

```
<div id="snaznav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="home">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
            <ul>
               <li style="display:block; float:none;"> <a href="#">Submenu1</a></li>
               <li style="display:block; float:none;"> <a href="#">Submenu2</a></li>
               <li style="display:block; float:none;"> <a href="#">Submenu3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```